# How should I code the situation to get data with json

Tags: python, json, api, web-scraping, python-requests

Suppose you are writing a python web client to access an API of an online supermarket. Given below are the API details.

Base URL= http://host1.open.uom.lk:8080

Write a python program to retrieve all the products from the API Server and print the total number of products currently stored in the server.

Hint: the json response will be of the following example format:

```json
{
    "message": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 85,
            "productName": "Araliya Basmathi Rice",
            "description": "White Basmathi Rice imported from Pakistan. High-quality rice with extra fragrance. Organically grown.",
            "category": "Rice",
            "brand": "CIC",
            "expiredDate": "2023.05.04",
            "manufacturedDate": "2022.02.20",
            "batchNumber": 324567,
            "unitPrice": 1020,
            "quantity": 200,
            "createdDate": "2022.02.24"
        },
        {
            "id": 86,
            "productName": "Araliya Basmathi Rice",
            "description": "White Basmathi Rice imported from Pakistan. High-quality rice with extra fragrance. Organically grown.",
            "category": "Rice",
            "brand": "CIC",
            "expiredDate": "2023.05.04",
            "manufacturedDate": "2022.02.20",
            "batchNumber": 324567,
            "unitPrice": 1020,
            "quantity": 200,
            "createdDate": "2022.02.24"
        }
    ]
}
```

Hi guys I'm stuck in a question based on python Web-scraping and i've been stuck in this question for more than one month.
Here's the codes I tried, I still can't think of what my mistake is...

1.

```
import requests
import json
BASE_URL= 'http://host1.open.uom.lk:8080'
response= requests.get(f"{BASE_URL}/api/products")
y=json.dumps(response,indent=5,sort_keys=True)
print(y)
```

2. 

```
import requests
import json
BASE_URL= 'http://host1.open.uom.lk:8080'
response= requests.get(f"{BASE_URL}/api/products")
print(response.json())
```

Comment: what is your expected output?, The "total number of products currently stored in the server"? What is in response.json()?

Comment: When i go to the url in question (http://host1.open.uom.lk:8080/api/products) the data field is empty, can you confirm the correct endpoint?

Comment: Yes, @EricOlsen same for me. Op if the JSON you posted is the correct format, the quantity is in ['data']['quantity']

Comment: @EricOlsen I tried using other endpoints but they don't seem to  exist

Answer (score 0):

Althougth your provided API endpoints do not seem to work i will try to provide a broader example for you  to play around with via the free api "CatFacts"

```
url = "https://catfact.ninja/facts"
import requests
import json
response= requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
print(json.dumps(response.json(),indent=4))
print(len(data["data"]))
```

Above we are accessing the "CatFacts" API and printing all the data that is retrieved from us. You will notice when you run this code your self (or go to https://catfact.ninja/facts) that there is a piece of the JSON returned called data that holds a list of cat facts. To find out how many cat facts we have we just call `len()` on the list of cat facts from our returned JSON object

Hopefully with this example you are able to get yours to work

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the sample data you provided, I assume that you need to calculate the sum of the quantity of each product to get the total number of products currently stored on the server

You can convert the json response to dictionary via json.load() function and iterate through its data

```
import requests
import json

BASE_URL= 'http://host1.open.uom.lk:8080'
response= requests.get(f"{BASE_URL}/api/products")

products = json.load(response)
total=0

for product in products['data']:
    total += product['quantity']
    
print(total)
```